# Next.js image display as broken image on some pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, mapbox-api-staticimages

Using Next Image works properly on root files in the page folder, but displays as a broken image on files in the sub-Folder in the page folder.[image]

Comment: can i see your code ?

Comment: Can we have more details, how are you referencing the image?

Comment: import Logo from "public/static/assets/img/muna_logo.png";

<div className={styles.logo}>
  <Image src={Logo} alt="muna logo" />
</div>;

Answer (score 3):

when you want import image or file in NextJs, you dont need write Public folder.

And you have to give  width and height of the tag image!
please read this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

```
<Image width={200} height={200} src={"/static/assets/img/muna_logo.png"} alt="muna logo" />
```